# Variable not passing through to javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, function, variables

Working on a like/dislike function for my blogpost site, and the variables won't flow through. I've stared at this for days, and cannot find the break as all of the code looks fine and I've included all the necessary pages containing varibales. Any insights?

This is the "button" I'm using for a "like" button:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="like_add('. $blabid .')" class="like">Like</a> <span id="likes" class="likereadout">' . $likes . '</span>
```

The id variable shows up correctly when I "inspect element", but won't pass through to the following Javafunction:

```
    function like_add(postid) {
     $.post('like_add.php', {postid:postid}, function(data) {
     if (data == 'success') {
     alert('Woohoo');
     } else { 
       alert('I need sleep.');
       }
      });
      }
```

The Javascript is supposed to pass the variable to like_add.php, which reads:

```
    <?php
    include 'init.php';
    if (isset($_POST['postid']) && article_exists($_POST['postid'])) {


    $postid = $_POST['postid'];

    if (previously_liked($postid) === true) {
    echo 'You\'ve already liked this!';
} else {
  add_like($postid);
  echo 'success';
  }
     }
     ?>
```

Which refs the following php functions included in the init.php file:

```
    function article_exists($postid) {
     $postid = (int)$postid;
     return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM 'blabbing' WHERE 'id' = $postid"), 0) == 0) ? false : true;
```

}

and:

```
    function add_like($postid) {
     $postid = (int)$postid;
     mysql_query("UPDATE 'blabbing' SET 'likes' = 'likes' + 1 WHERE 'id'= $postid");
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'likes' ('user_id', 'id') VALUES ($ip, $postid)");
     }
```

Realllll new to all of this, so please go easy on me. Thank you so much for your help!

```
function article_exists($postid) {
     $postid = (int)$postid;
     return (mysql_result(mysql_query(
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript ! Please fix the title of your question not to confuse anyone.

Comment: where did u connect to your DB?

Comment: try changing your queries, expecially delete those apostrophes around the table names and the attributes... I usually write like "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ' ".$id." ' " - in case id is a varchar

Answer (score 0):

When you send AJAX data throught $.post, it have to be stringified:

```
$.post('like_add.php', JSON.stringify({postid:postid}), function(data) {
```